# C++ Derived Class

Tags: c++

My assignment is a Binary Search Tree derived from a Binary Tree, in my driver program this is how I've created a BST object. But I am slightly confused because I know there must be a constructor but no where in my assignment does it actually call for a constructor for the derived class.

```
int main() {
   int x = 0;
   int n = 0;
   int len = 0;
   int total = 0;
   int seed = 0;
   bool y;
   cin >> n;

   vector<int> v;
   binSTree<int> t;
```

I'm having a hard time using these "pre" and "code" tags, the vector is actually `vector<int> v;` and the tree is really `binSTree<int> t;` With less than and greater signs around the int of course.

the error in my program is as follows:

```
In file included from prog6.cc:2:
    binSTree.h:1:9: error: macro names must be identifiers
prog6.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
prog6.cc:16: error: ‘binSTree’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: SO doesn't use the HTML code tag for code, but anything indented by four spaces will be displayed as code including all angle brackets.

Comment: Can you show us the header file `binSTree.h`? Do you `#include "binSTree.h" in `prog6.cc`?

Comment: Also, you've not shown the code where the error is.  What's on line 1 of binSTree.h ?

Comment: @birryree: I can't think of any other explanation for "In file included from prog6.cc:2: binSTree.h".  Not only do we know there's a #include, we know it's on line 2.

Comment: @Ben Voigt silly me - but @Greg Laubenstein - please show us the header. Also, does the '@' work for names with spaces?

Comment: @birryree: It works fine for any name provided there's a colon after, but SO is also just a bit off when it comes to notification at times. Also, you only need the name up to the first space.

Comment: not to sound too foolish but how do I upload my header file?

Comment: @Greg, just edit the question and put it a code block like I did with the rest of your code excerpts.  That means indenting all lines with 4 extra spaces, and there's a little code button in the question and answer editor that will indent the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the base class is default constructable, and the derived class does not make an explicit call to the base class constructor, the compiler inserts a call to the default base class constructor before calling the derived class constructor.

but that's got nothing to do with the error you are encountering, which is:

```
In file included from prog6.cc:2:
    binSTree.h:1:9: error: macro names must be identifiers
```

Remember, always ***always*** look at the first error your compiler produces, not the one at the bottom.  This means you have, someplace in `binSTree.h`, on the first few lines, something like

```
#define ...
```

where the dots are something invalid.

Comment: thankyou I will have to keep that in mind, I messed up my #ifndef ... #define ... statements thanks again!

Comment: Does that 'always always' rule apply for templates as well? I feel it gives  more context if I scroll down to see where the error comes from during instantiaton.

Comment: @Chubsdad: well, with templates, it's pretty much a crapshoot, but the reasoning is because the compiler should probably stop as soon as it encounters an error, because by definition, the compiler can't guess what you mean your code to do anymore.  Some compilers try to parse past the error anyway, because they want to show you as much information about your code as possible.